# Checks for webserver response

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm making this folder scanner on a website, 
but after 2 successful urls it will crash and i got no idea why.

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    StreamReader file = null;

    file = new StreamReader(filePath);

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        var url = new Uri(txtUrl.Text + line);
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Win32)";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //Directory.ListView.Items.Add(url.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(url.ToString() + "Success");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(url.ToString() + " fail: " + err.Message);
        }

    }
    if (file != null)
        file.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("done;");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file you are trying to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your HTTPWebResponse object,

```
response.Close()
```

Comment: Yes, I would use a try-catch-finally approach and close it in the finally. I have killed IIS of all development machines in a former company I have been working because of a check-in without the response.Close.  don't remember now but if response is disposable you could use the using block.

Comment: using is good although -depends on the pattern- but generally with HTTPWebResponse I always ending up implementing try-catch-finally

Comment: @mikkel: forget try-catch-finally. Just use `using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())`. Much simpler, and cleans up for you.